# Share different kinds of items to NSSharingServicePicker?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Say I want to share an image, some text and a arbitrary file (a plist for example).

If I try to use the NSSharingServicePicker it displays only sharing services that can handle **all three types**.  So it wont show Air Drop because it does not support the text, and it wont show Twitter or Facebook because of the file, and it wont show Acorn because of the file and the text.

I want to offer to share whatever is available to each service (so Acorn would get just the image, and Air Drop the file and the image, and Mail and Messages would get all three.

Is there any way to do this using NSSharingServicePicker?

I really do not want to have to resort to implementing my own picker, processing all the sharing types and do all the work myself (including Recent lists and More… options).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just augment the list of services using the delegate callback?

You can get references to the services you want ahead of time using `sharingServices(forItems: [Any]) -> [NSSharingService]` and by passing in one type at a time to multiple calls, then use the delegate to populate the picker with your list of services.

The only sticking point I foresee (without trying it, sorry) is once a service is chosen I wonder which type of item will be passed to it.

EDIT: Original suggestion:

> You might have to use the delegate method `func sharingServicePicker(_ sharingServicePicker: NSSharingServicePicker, didChoose service: NSSharingService?)` to invoke the service yourself, with the correct
> data type, and pass in something to the `NSSharingServicePicker`
> initially which will be sure to fail.

I attempted to call `perform` on service from this delegate method and I get a crash in the internals. :/

/EDIT

From the `NSSharingServicePickerDelegate` docs:

`func sharingServicePicker(NSSharingServicePicker, sharingServicesForItems: [Any], proposedSharingServices: [NSSharingService]) -> [NSSharingService]`

> Invoked to allow the delegate to customize exactly what appears in the sharing service picker before it is presented.
>
> The delegate can reorder, remove default services or add custom
> services before the picker is presented. It's possible to add custom
> services by mutating the proposedSharingServices array and adding new
> NSSharingService instances.
>
> The following is an example:

```
    NSMutableArray *sharingServices = [proposedServices mutableCopy];
    NSSharingService * customService = [[[NSSharingService alloc]   initWithTitle:@"Service Title"
                                                                    image:image alternateImage:alternateImage
                                                                    handler:^{
                                                                        [self doCustomServiceWithItems:items];
                                       }] autorelease];
    [sharingServices addObject:customService];
    return [sharingServices autorelease];
```

> Availability
>
> macOS 10.8+